# Ways & Methods switch between MongoDB Database after selecting a country. (MERNG)

Tags: database, development-process, node.js, server, mongodb

I have a concept in which a user selects a country, which will either filter or go to that database; I was thinking of alternatives or options that would help in the process. These are my first plans or thoughts for the idea's specific options. And before I go further, I am currently using the MERNG (MongoDB, Express, React (NextJs), Nodejs, Graphql (using Apollo)) Stack to give you a heads up.

## OPTIONS

---

### Option 1:

I thought maybe I would put the object key in every collection in MongoDB. Something like this, for example:

[image]

In this way, I can filter it through the use of the find like **Post.find({ country: CountryName})** something like that.

But I was while I was doing that, I thought that it might be a hassle since I have to put object key country in every collection, which is much work. It does help solve my problem, but I wanted it to be simple, so on to the second option.

### Option 2:

For this option, I thought of making two databases: Country A Database and Country B Database. After I select the country in the frontend, I thought that I am using React will connect to that particular database.

[image]

I thought this was the best option since both data are separated, such as collections that contain the object or data of users and more. But the problem is the execution of it. I can't imagine how I could after I give the server that, for example, USA is the country I selected, how while the database connection change and furthermore.

That's all the options I could think of right now. Is there another way to make this possible? If not, could you please give me an example of the process I'm trying to make? Because I am currently not that good at switching between MongoDB databases, I honestly don't know how to do it. If you could provide an example of the code below, I would appreciate it. If you don't understand what I mean, please comment down below. If you can, I will explain it. Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to show only data related to a single country? Is there any possibility a user might want to see data from multiple countries? Also keep into consideration users in a border area or visiting a foreign country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably keep your objects in one collection and add a `country` key.

Do you ever want to perform operations across all countries? Then keep those objects in the same collection. If you split your objects across multiple databases or collections, this will make cross-collection operations much more difficult. In essence, you are creating your own database index structure instead of using the database's built-in indexing features. And you are not removing the country field, you are merely representing implicitly.

In contrast, your objection to keeping the data in one collection seems fairly minor. You complain about adding a `country` field to every object, arguing that “might be a hassle” and that “is much work”. I disagree. This field is added *by software.* You only need to write the software once, and it will then handle this field for all posts that are processed via this software. Your software needs to manage countries in any case: it needs to know about the country if using a single collection and filtering for objects with a matching country key, but it also needs to know about the country when using different collections because the code would have to know which collection to use.

So on balance I think that using multiple collections or databases will not simplify your software. It does not seem to have any advantages over using a single collection. The difference is purely in how you represent the information about a country – implicitly via the collection or explicitly via a field in your objects. I suspect that the explicit representation will be simpler overall.

That is not to say that it will always be simpler. If the data for different countries in essence relate to different instances of your applications, then it could indeed make sense to have separate databases (this is the old debate about designing multi-tenant systems). But the decisive factor for determining which data goes into which database would not be “different countries” but “different instances”. It just happens that you might be using separate instances for different countries. But I suspect that you are not deploying separate instances of your application per country, so that it also makes little sense to deploy different databases or collections per country.

Comment: I see, thanks for you reply I understand what you mean and trying to point out I was thinking the same thing at first but was hesitant since I thought there is always a better way and what I am always doing is inefficient considering how less experience I have but you answered my question flawlessly. Thank you  :)